# crear array anidado

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, push

Quiero hacer esta variable que esta dentro de un metodo each array pero no lo logro, son datos dinamicos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando lo intento salen vacios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por que estoy tratando de hacer array anidados

pero como se ve en la imgen nivel aparece en o, pero necesito hacerlo un array
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debe verse asi.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo estoy tratando de hacer asi.
List es un array estatico.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todas estas imagenes son formas en que estoy tratando de hacerlo

```
$('.JSON').each(function () {
      var data = [];
      var acciones = $(this).attr('accion');
      var subacciones = $(this).attr('subaccion');
     
          for (var i = 3; i <= 4; i++) {
            var array = [acciones];
            data.push(array);
            data.push({ list: [] });
            data[data.length - 1].list.push(new Array(subacciones));

          }
        console.log(data);

    });
```

Comment: Por favor puedes añadir la parte del código donde generas ese array y los datos que debe llevar? Con tan poca información se hace muy difícil poder ayudar a resolver tu problema

Comment: Esas son las formas en las que he tratado, gracias por leer

Comment: @giovaniotero el código va como texto por favor

Comment: @BetaM  ese es el código que uso, quierosaber si puedo hacer que acciones sean como list

Answer (score 1):

Es un poco problemático ayudarte si no se tiene la información completa de lo que se desea obtener y cuáles datos debe de llevar, de cualquier forma, responderé suponiendo que quieres la estructura que muestras en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Anidado]

Lo que buscas en realidad no es un arreglo anidado, es un [objeto](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/javascript/javascript-object) cómo tal, todas las formas que has intentado tienen problemas ya que agregan elementos al array, suponiendo que quieres tener la misma estructura de lista y nivel, solamente es necesario hacer lo siguiente:

```
// Primer ejemplo con list
var data = {
        list:{}
      }
      var acciones = ['action_1','action_2','action_3','action_4'];
      var subacciones = ['subaction_1'  ,'subaction_2', 'subaction_3', 'subaction_4'];
      acciones.forEach(function(accion){
        data.list.nivel = subacciones
      });
      console.log(data);
      
// Segundo ejemplo asignando todas las subacciones a cada accion


      var data2 = {}
      var acciones = ['action_1','action_2','action_3','action_4'];
      var subacciones = ['subaction_1'  ,'subaction_2', 'subaction_3', 'subaction_4'];
      acciones.forEach(function(accion){
        data2[accion] = subacciones
      });
      console.log(data2);
Prueba acciones
```

Answer (score 0):

list[0][0]= 'FRUTA'
list[0][1]=['manzana','naranja','pera']

?te vale?. si, como dice cooper, pones código, quizás te podamos ayudar mas

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], ayudaría mucho consideres editar y explicar tu aporte

Comment: Esas son las formas en las que he tratado, gracias por leer